# Has anyone got all the badges on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, badges

I am just wondering, does anyone have all the badges on Stack Overflow?

Comment: If you would have had a look you'd know that this is not possible.

Comment: 1. Go to the badges list 2. Find the badge with the least number of recipients 3. Go through that list and see if any of those users are missing a badge.  The smallest list is actually quite small, and most of those users can be disqualified. in a fraction of a second by just glancing at their badge counts.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No, no one has all badges on Stack Overflow.

It is not possible.

For example - the [Precognitive](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/892/precognitive) badge cannot be awarded, as the site existed before the Area51 process came to being.

This of course excludes all tag badges, which would require someone to have score of 1000 in each and every tag...

Comment: [Constable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/3108/constable) is a similarly unattainable badge. The badges like Legendary (150 days of 200 rep. gain) probably do not correlate with Unsung Hero (25% of answers zero score and accepted), but with 7,657 unsung heroes it is not entirely implausible that one of the 166 legendary users would also be unsung. It seems like it should be possible to use the [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/) to answer this question, but I do not know what terms to use to search for an existing query.

Comment: I have Legendary but not Unsung. There, only 165 more users to check. :-P

Comment: Actually, it took only a few checks to find [xdazz](http://stackoverflow.com/users/762073/xdazz), [adil](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1298762/adil) and [jon-lin](http://stackoverflow.com/users/851273/jon-lin), all of whom have both Legendary and Unsung! Not that rare a combo then.

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton Please see my answer for a Data Explorer query. (Would welcome any suggestions for improvements).

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the question is referring to only the top level badges that aren't for specific technologies, [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1354513) lists the StackOverflow users with the most distinct badges.

At the time of writing there are two joint top users, who each have 84 out of a possible 91 badges. However, it's worth noting that some of the badges have now been retired (see [bottom of this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges)) and so are permanently unattainable for users who do not already have them.